# ExtJS 4 form textfield and color (background)

Tags: extjs, background, textfield

There is simple form and some textfields on this form. I have to set colors
(background and font) in two of them on runtime.

I tried to do it two ways:

1) `fieldInstance.addClass('aaa')`  with css like this

```
.aaa .x-form-field  {
        background-color: black;
        color: red;
   }
```

2) `fieldInstance.setFieldStyle('font-weight: bold;color: red;background-color: black;');`

both methods are working because I see the bottom age of both is 
fields is thick in black color, and both fields are working the same (almost) way.

Before enter and after exit background color is white.
When I start to edit this fields, background of first
is always white, background of the second is black until
I leave the field.

[image]

Could you explain me whats wrong?

Comment: Form definition is the following:  <br>                     xtype: 'form',
                            itemId: 'FORM_CZAS',
                            bodyStyle: 'background-color: #DFE8F6',
                            border: false,
                            margin: '10, 0, 0, 0',

Answer (score 0):

I think that the 1st function append a class to the Others already presents.
In the second case you replace values of style already setted.
Maybe to have the same issue you need to modify the x-form-field fields, instead of append Others.

I Always use the second option if i have to modify style on Runtime.

maybe posting other code i can see better where the problem could present

Answer (score 0):

For `<input>` element applied many classes beside `x-form-field`, like `x-form-text` and some of them define `color` and `background-color` aswell. So I guess that some of that classes may be more specific than `.aaa .x-form-field`. Try to use `!important` within your CSS rules:

```
.aaa .x-form-field  {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: When I corrected my css I found only one difference - now both fields are working the same way - when I start both backgrounds are black.

Comment: @Tad Hmmm, my other guess is that you apply styles to `textfield` `<div>` element and inner `<input>` element is "above" div. Try change CSS selector to `.aaa .x-form-field input`.